# can not start module mod_http_offline in ejabberd 15.11

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd version 15.11 and erlang/OTP 17.
I am facing problem in adding mod_http_offline module.
I can compile it successfully, but when I add module initialization in ejabberd.yml it can not start module.
here is my error logs about the problem,

```
2015-12-04 14:27:17.435 [critical] <0.4264.0>@gen_mod:start_module:106 Problem starting the module mod_http_offline 
for host <<"host">>
 options: []
 error: undef
[{ejabberd_logger,info_msg,
                  [mod_http_offline,20,"mod_http_offline loading",[]],
                  []},
 {mod_http_offline,start,2,[{file,"src/mod_http_offline.erl"},
 {line,20}]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,98}]},
 {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},
 {ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,73}]},
 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
 [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]
```

I have already refer below question:
[INFO_MSG method fails in ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673914/info-msg-method-fails-in-ejabberd)

any little guidance will be a great help,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile it from the ejabberd source repository. It is not compile with the same logging option that ejabberd itself.

Comment: hey @Mickaël Rémond, thanks for your answer, I have solved this issue.but somehow my mod_http_offline hook is not being called. can you help me on this.